# Sql Subquery Syntax

Tags: sql

I want to execute a subquery using the current customer ID as I try to describe below

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Customer_Id, 
(SELECT SUM  (total) FROM Orders where Customer_Id = Customer_Id AND CAST(Date) > DayIspecify )  
FROM Orders  where shop_id= '1-9THT'
```

What I want is to calculate the SUM each customer spent over a specified time period on the specific shop.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: you don't want a subquery but group by

Comment: Do you want the value of orders placed at shop 1-9THT, broken down by customer, or do you want customers with the values of *all* their orders, where *any* of their orders was placed through shop 1-9THT?

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase my question. I want to select the SUM over a period of time that I will specify

Comment: OK - do you have a separate customer table?

Comment: No the only table I have is Orders. And each customer appears many times

Comment: OK - I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated) Try:

```
select Customer_Id, 
       sum(case when o.shop_id = '1-9THT' and Date > DayIspecify 
                then total else 0 end) total
from Orders
group by Customer_Id
```

- to return all customers recorded on the Orders table, together with the values of any of their orders placed through shop 1-9THT *after* the date specified. (Change `>` to `>=` to make it *on or after* the date specified.)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Customer_Id, SUM(total) SumTotal
FROM Orders
where shop_id= '1-9THT' 
group by Customer_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Not require subquery 
Try this:

```
SELECT Customer_Id,SUM(total)FROM Orders WHERE shop_id='1-9THT' GROUP BY Customer_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQL GroupBy](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Customer_Id,  SUM  (total) FROM Orders  where shop_id= '1-9THT' group by customer_Id
```